# What is consent id in api?

Tags: api

I am working on a project that collects my last transactions from my bank accounts. I am using ziraat and garanti bbva banks but, on their api documentation there is something called consent id and i cant find it anywhere. And btw if someone can give me any advices about this api's it will be great.

```
{
  "consentId": "1daac6c2-9fd1-55c6-a926-c3f2247405ab",
  "unitNum": "295",
  "accountNum": "6291296",
  "IBAN": "TR620006200029500006291296"
}
```

Comment: I really hope that's a fake IBAN/account number

Comment: Ofc bro its fake :d

Comment: You'd be surprised how often people accidentally leak API keys on here.

Comment: Well, I hope that some time maybe i will be a software developer like you and warn people about that things. :*)